# Promesa sin resolver

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
getUserAccount : function(){
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $http.get(CommonUtilitiesService.getUrl()+'AllUserAccount')                     
            .then(function(response){
                if(response.status === 200){
                    if(response.data.message != '' && response.data.type=='warning'){
                        delay.reject(response.data.data);
                        swal({title: '',type: response.data.type,text: response.data.message});
                    }else{                                                          
                        delay.resolve(response.data.data);
                    }
                }
            })

            return delay.promise;
```

Mi problema es que al ejecutar obtengo La siguiente promesa. ¿Cómo podría resolverla?.

[image: 1]

Comment: Como estas usando la función getUserAccount?  Te recuerdo que como estás usando $q o una promesa es necesario agregar un then. Algo así: `getUserAccount().then(function(resp){ console.log(resp)})`

Answer (score 0):

La resolvería de la siguiente manera:

```
getUserAccount
  .then(function(data){
       // CODIGO_ACA
  })
  .catch(function(error){
  });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional en plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3B4Xe21kZFrJQXZNCgiZ?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, en caso contrario, no dudes en volver a preguntar.

Answer (score -1):

tendrías que resolverla con `.then(success, error)` pasandole como parametros dos funciones para los casos de Success o Error.

```
getUserAccount().then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    //TU CODIGO
}, function(error){
    console.log(error)
    //TU CODIGO DE ERROR
});
```